# how to connect to couchdb database using couchdb4j api with username and password?

Tags: couchdb

I am using couchdb4j api to establish a connection through session object with couchdb(version 0.11.2).
Couchdb database is protected with username and password, 
trying to establish connection with
*Session(String host, int port, String user, String pass, boolean usesAuth, boolean secure)* constructor by providing host,port,user,pass and usersAuth true, secure false,
but it is unable to establish a connection with username and password and giving a warning  **Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}.**
 I used correct username and password.

Comment: Are you able to access the database directly, using curl for example? What are the results of something like curl http://<username>:<password>@localhost:5984/_session ?

Comment: Testing with curl is complicated because some password characters are invalid to the shell, and others are invalid to curl. Since curl is easy, I agree to try it first. If that fails, try logging in from the browser with Futon. At least that will confirm the basics, name lookup, networking, and authentication.

Comment: @Colin Ross,  Yes i am able to access it from curl, here is the response for http://<username>:<password>@localhost:5984/_session     **{"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":"admin","roles":["_admin"]},"info":{"authentication_db":"_users","authentication_handlers":[""],"authenticated":""}}**

Comment: Interesting - when I do the equivalent, I have an array of authentication handlers, including "oauth", "cookie" and "default". Also, my "authenticated" field has the value "default". Perhaps you have disabled / haven't enabled the appropriate handlers? Can you log in with Futon?

Comment: @Colin Ross, I enabled the handlers and set require_valid_user=true, then i got handlers in the response for /_session, **{"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":"admin","roles":["_admin"]},"info":{"authentication_db":"_users","authentication_handlers":["oauth","cookie","default"],"authenticated":"default"}}**. But same authentication error while accessing database

Comment: Are you trying to access the database with the same credentials you are trying with curl?

Comment: Yes i am using same credentials in java app what i used with curl.

Comment: hi even i am facing the same problem ,please help me if you get the solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try a CouchDB lib that is actively maintained http://www.ektorp.org/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue by writing a simple Curl class that simplified the communication and return JSON in String form, since that is what is returned.

It should be self explanatory and you can read the main method for hints.

```
package path.to.the.class;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import Log;

/**
 * This class takes on the simple task of doing http calls to any http web service like a web page or alike. Since the
 * class is streamlined for JSON use this is the most easiest to set up.
 * 
 * @author mikael.p.larsson@epsilon.nu
 * 
 */
public class Curl {
    private Map<String, String> requestProperties = null;
    private String charsetName = "UTF8";

    public static final String GET = "GET";
    public static final String PUT = "PUT";
    public static final String POST = "POST";
    public static final String HEAD = "HEAD";
    public static final String DELETE = "DELETE";

    /**
     * This is the default constructor for Curl which takes it for granted that you want to communicate and read JSON.
     * Most of the times this approach works even if plain html or text is requested.
     */
    public Curl() {
        requestProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        requestProperties.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    /**
     * With this alternate constructor a map containing header strings can be provided, useful if something apart from
     * JSON is to be consumed.
     * 
     * @param requestProperties
     *            a Map containing the header strings.
     */
    public Curl(Map<String, String> requestProperties) {
        this.requestProperties = requestProperties;
    }

    /**
     * Public setter to enable setting charsetName.
     * 
     * @param charsetName
     * @return this instance to enable on liners.
     */
    public Curl setCharsetName(String charsetName) {
        this.charsetName = charsetName;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * In the world of the web this is the command that a web browser does for you after you have entered an url into
     * the address field. When using GET there should be no side effects on the site the data was requested from; the
     * get method only consumes data and sends nothing.
     * 
     * @param urlAsString
     *            the url to fetch from the internet.
     * @return The response from the server
     */
    public String get(String urlAsString) {
        return doHttpCall(urlAsString, GET, null);
    }

    /**
     * Put should be used when a resource should be sent to a server.
     * 
     * @param urlAsString
     *            the url to the resource.
     * @param doc
     *            the content to put
     * @return The response from the server.
     */
    public String put(String urlAsString, String doc) {
        return doHttpCall(urlAsString, "PUT", doc);
    }

    /**
     * Post should be used when a resource should be posted to a server.
     * 
     * @param urlAsString
     *            the url to the resource.
     * @param doc
     *            the content to put
     * @return The response from the server.
     */
    public String post(String urlAsString, String doc) {
        return doHttpCall(urlAsString, "POST", doc);
    }

    /**
     * Mostly to be considered as a get without the contents, Here implemented as an is the resource available function.
     * 
     * @param urlAsString
     *            the url to the resource.
     * @return The responseMessage from the server.
     */
    public String head(String urlAsString) {
        return doHttpCall(urlAsString, "HEAD", null);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a resource from an url. Be careful!
     * 
     * @param urlAsString
     *            The url to the resource to delete.
     * @return The response from the server.
     */
    public String delete(String urlAsString) {
        try {
            return doHttpCall(urlAsString, "DELETE", null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.warn("No object to delete found at " + urlAsString + ".");
            return "No object to delete found at " + urlAsString + ".";
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method does the actual HTTP communication to simplify the methods above.
     * 
     * @param urlAsString
     *            The url to resource in question.
     * @param method
     *            The method to be used.
     * @param doc
     *            The resource to send or null if none.
     * @return The response from the server.
     */
    private String doHttpCall(String urlAsString, String method, String doc) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlAsString);
            httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod(method);

            if (url.getUserInfo() != null) {
                String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(url.getUserInfo().getBytes()));
                httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
            }
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
            for (String key : requestProperties.keySet()) {
                httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty(key, requestProperties.get(key));
            }

            if (doc != null && !doc.isEmpty()) {
                httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + doc.getBytes(charsetName));

                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream(),
                        charsetName);
                outputStreamWriter.write(doc);
                outputStreamWriter.close();

            }

            readInputStream(result, httpUrlConnection.getInputStream());

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.info(e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.warn("The url '" + urlAsString + "' is malformed.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                result.append(e.getMessage());
                readInputStream(result, httpUrlConnection.getErrorStream());
                if ("".equals(result.toString())) {
                    result.append("Error ");
                    result.append(httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode());
                    result.append(" : ");
                    result.append(httpUrlConnection.getResponseMessage());
                    result.append(".  Exception message is: [");
                    result.append(e.getMessage());
                    result.append("]");
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            }
        } finally {
            if ("HEAD".equalsIgnoreCase(method)) {
                try {
                    result.append(httpUrlConnection.getResponseMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.fatal("This is as low as we can get, nothing worked!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (httpUrlConnection != null)
                httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Local helper method that reads data from an inputstream.
     * 
     * @param result
     *            The read text.
     * @param inputStream
     *            The stream to read.
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void readInputStream(StringBuffer result, InputStream inputStream) throws UnsupportedEncodingException,
            IOException {
        if (inputStream == null)
            throw new IOException("No working inputStream.");
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charsetName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

        String row;
        while ((row = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(row);
            result.append("\n");
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
        streamReader.close();
    }

    /**
     * A main method to provide the possibility to use this exact class from the command line.
     * <p>
     * usage:
     * <code>java -cp target/classes/. path.to.the.class.Curl http://server.domain.nu:port/path/to/resource method [data]</code>
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param args
     *            in order: url method data
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("usage: Curl path method [data]");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String url = args[0];
        String method = args[1];
        String data = args.length == 3 ? args[2] : null;
        Curl curl = new Curl();

        if (method.equals("head")) {
            System.out.println(curl.head(url));
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (method.equals("put")) {
            System.out.println(curl.put(url, data));
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println(curl.doHttpCall(url, method, data));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change configuration parameter required_valid_user to true