# How to use wget in java

Tags: java, html, download

I have tried two methods to load this html page: http://www.compare-cellphones.org/Apple-iPhone-5-vs-Apple-iPhone-4S

1.Using openStream()
2.Using Connection.get()

Both methods are working for getting HTML pages of other sites but not the above site.
I am trying to use wget also..

ANY help for getting this HTML page downloaded using java required.
A working code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my Curl example here to get ideas:

[how to connect to couchdb database using couchdb4j api with username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567320/how-to-connect-to-couchdb-database-using-couchdb4j-api-with-username-and-passwor/14241612#14241612)

The question is about CouchDB but the answer isn't really.